# Why does 14.10 remove Empathy?

Tags: empathy, 14.10

I had installed 14.04 Trusty Tahr sometime earlier this year and it came with [Empathy](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/empathy) preinstalled. I then upgraded to 14.10 this morning, and I saw it removed Empathy and any plug-ins.

Why was it removed as the default IM application?

Comment: Empathy has build requirements that use `nautilus-sendto`, Ubuntu is moving away from nautilus as far as I know. See the changelog: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+source/empathy/3.8.6-0ubuntu13

Answer (score -1):

I am using the 64bit version of Ubuntu 14.10 and it has Empathy[image]

They might have removed it from the 32bit version? You could always download it from the Ubuntu Software Centre

Comment: I am definitely using the 64bit version. Yes, I could download it, but I still think it's weird.

Comment: Hmm, when you installed did you tick the checkbox(s) that said Install Updates and Install this third party software?

Comment: @RedCat23 [packages.ubuntu.com: Empathy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/empathy) shows its still available for amd64 and 32bit?

Comment: The installer had no checkboxes, nor did it prompt me to install updates or the such. It only listed the packages it will remove, the ones it will install and the ones it will upgrade, and I had to accept that.

Comment: @blade19899 It might be still available, but not installed by default?

Comment: When you installed Ubunty you should have seen this http://assets.ubuntu.com/sites/ubuntu/latest/u/img/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop/image-installdesktoplongtermsupport-2.jpg As you can see there are two checkboxes labelled 'Download Updates while Installing' and 'Install this thrid-party software' did you tick them?

Comment: It seems that the an upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10 will remove Empathy whereas the fresh install of 14.10 still comes preloaded with Empathy.

Comment: That would appear to be the case.

Comment: One could still manually install it right?: `sudo apt-get install empathy`

Comment: I did not do a fresh install of 14.10. I simply upgraded to it when prompted by the update manager.

Comment: Maybe it caused problems when upgrading so they removed it from the upgrade package, just a guess.

Comment: @blade19899 You can, however, it doesn't work with goa (gnome-online-accounts) any more and uses its internal accounts config instead (restoring the integration is cumbersome and unclear due to goa vs. uoa "war").